# Auto sending email application

Tags: c#, email

I'm going to develop a website which helps to send email to many email address. This site allows user register account. After user adding his email address (for example: abc@gmail.com, abc@xxx.com), he can create the list of emails that he want to send. Then he click send and email will be sent to people who be in the list.

So the question is do I need a step to config his email information? I meant he can enter the smtp server, port...for his email. for example: he uses the gmail -> abc@gmail.com. He needs to input

*Google Gmail Incoming Mail Server (POP3) - pop.gmail.com (SSL enabled, port 995)
    Outgoing Mail Server - use the SMTP mail server address provided by your local ISP or smtp.gmail.com (TLS enabled, port 587)*

Comment: if you only gonna use mails from Google Mail, they all use the same SMTP. you need it only once.  Use smtp.gmail.com when instantiate SMTP object. Also, if you're gonna use distincts mails, you'll need to provide the smpt for each one.

Comment: Are the emails going to be sent using email account(s) of your own? Or are they going to be sent using the user's email address?

Comment: @ELVieejo: I'm going to use distincts email for any user email

Comment: @Talon876: User cans chose any email

Comment: This sounds way too much like a Spamming-As-a-Service website...

Comment: @thkala:  not really, just a subcription function :)

Answer (score 2):

It won't work.

1)  Many users won't know their e-mail server details.

2)  Many mail servers won't accept outgoing mail from IPs not in their domain.

Comment: Yeah. When reality says your project will not work, do not do the project. Bad ideas do not get bette when you try surreal things. SPF and DOmain Keys are done to stop exactly this typ of spamming.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install / enable SMTP server on the same server as the Web Server. Provide a page where the users can enter From & to addresses.  Send email from your server but "spoof" the "from" email id.  This way users do not have to enter their email server details.

```
    public void SendEmailAsync(string id, string to, string from, string subject, string message, SendCompletedEventHandler callback)
    {
        // Command line argument must the the SMTP host.
        var client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"]);

        if (bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PickupDirectoryFromIis"]))
        {
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
        }


        // Specify the message content.
        var message = new MailMessage(from, to)
                          {
                              Subject = subject,
                              Body = message,
                              BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                              SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                          };

        client.SendCompleted += callback;
        try
        {
            client.SendAsync(message, id);
        }
        catch (SmtpException e)
        {
            this.EventLog.WriteEntry(e.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, and do you have any idea about the question "How to check if the email is read or not?"...

Comment: @"Bac Clunky":  Use an external Email provider such as SendGrid who have APIs to detect such a thing.